# requests.post returns a response for a 404 Error page - data parameters/form data the issue?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, http-status-code-404

Trying to use "requests.post()" to submit form data. The code runs successfully, but the request that it returns is a 404 Error page. I know for a fact that the URL I am using is correct. I have a feeling that the data parameters I am using are the problem, but am not sure.

The reason I believe the data parameters are the problem is because when I view the form data for the URL, it shows two other parameters: "utf8" and "authenticity_token". A screenshot of the form data can be found in the hyperlink below.

[Form Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z174x.png)

**Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

main = requests.get('https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(main, 'html.parser')

# print(soup.prettify())

url = 'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter'
post_params = {'group': 'ufc', 'schedule': 'results', 'sport': 'all', 'region': ''}
response = requests.post(url, data=post_params)

print(response.text)
```

**Output from "print(response.text)"**

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>
...
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example how to post data to this site:

```
import re
import ast
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter"
api_url = "https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter_events"

params = {
    "utf8": "✓",
    "authenticity_token": "",
    "group": "all",
    "schedule": "upcoming",
    "sport": "all",
    "region": "",
}

headers = {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Accept": "text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    params["authenticity_token"] = soup.select_one('[name="csrf-token"]')[
        "content"
    ]

    data = s.post(api_url, data=params, headers=headers).text
    data = re.search(
        r'\$\("\.fightcenterEvents"\)\.html\((".*")\);', data
    ).group(1)
    data = ast.literal_eval(data).replace(r"\/", "/")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

# print some data:
for name, dt in zip(
    soup.select(".fcListing .name"), soup.select(".fcListing .datetime")
):
    print(
        "{:<50} {}".format(name.get_text(strip=True), dt.get_text(strip=True))
    )
```

Prints:

```
Yanagi vs. Kiyota                                  Tuesday, April 27,  3:00 AM ET
ONE on TNT 4                                       Wednesday, April 28, 10:00 PM ET
Senrima Super Fight vol. 62                        Thursday, April 29,  3:00 AM ET
PFL 2021 #2                                        Thursday, April 29,  5:30 PM ET
Babilon MMA 21                                     Friday, April 30, 10:00 AM ET
MMA Festival 2021                                  Friday, April 30, 10:00 AM ET
Mthalane vs. Edwards                               Friday, April 30,  2:30 PM ET
Mega Fight Champions 3                             Friday, April 30,  5:00 PM ET
BKFC 17                                            Friday, April 30,  7:00 PM ET
Fonseca vs. Zamora                                 Friday, April 30,  7:00 PM ET
CES 62                                             Friday, April 30,  8:00 PM ET
Who's #1: Craig Jones vs Tye Ruotolo               Friday, April 30,  8:00 PM ET
East vs. West                                      Friday, April 30,  8:00 PM ET
Bastida vs. Villalobos                             Friday, April 30,  8:00 PM ET
Cruzat vs. Orosco                                  Friday, April 30,  8:30 PM ET
Marriaga vs. Garcia                                Friday, April 30,  9:00 PM ET
UWC Mexico 26                                      Friday, April 30,  9:00 PM ET
Dominium Fighter Championship 5                    Saturday, May 01, 12:00 AM ET
OKTAGON 23                                         Saturday, May 01, 12:00 AM ET
Messapicum Fighting Championship 3                 Saturday, May 01, 12:00 AM ET
Kiatpetch Super Fight                              Saturday, May 01,  3:00 AM ET
Dynamic Glove 599                                  Saturday, May 01,  3:00 AM ET
Charunphak vs. Lerasan                             Saturday, May 01,  3:00 AM ET
XFC 49                                             Saturday, May 01,  4:00 AM ET
GFC 05                                             Saturday, May 01,  4:00 AM ET
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I wasn't including headers when posting or requesting.